# MQTT can not connect to AWS server

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, notifications, mqtt

I have an android app that was tested on mobile phones using Android 8/9/10/11/12, and Android 8/9/10/11 phones are working normally, but I can’t receive notifications on android 12. Can anyone make any suggestions?

The exception I am getting (Only Android 12)!
"MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found."

further information(2021/12/2)

1. This app is used to connect the AWS server.
2. Android 8/9/10/11 phones are normal, only android 12 has an error message.
   So I don't think it is a problem with the AWS server.

Here is my sample code:

```
    public static AmazonClientManager clientManager = null;
    String clientId;
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;
    AWSIotMqttManager mqttManager;
    AWSIotClient mIotAndroidClient;
    String keystorePath;
    String keystoreName;
    String keystorePassword;
    String certificateId;
    KeyStore clientKeyStore = null;

    private static final Regions MY_REGION = Regions.xx_xxxx_x;
    private static final String COGNITO_POOL_ID = "my-cognito-pool-id";
    private static final String CUSTOMER_SPECIFIC_ENDPOINT = "My-Endpoint";
    private static final String KEYSTORE_NAME = "my_keystore";
    private static final String KEYSTORE_PASSWORD = "my_password";
    private static final String CERTIFICATE_ID = "my_certificate_id";
    private static final String AWS_IOT_POLICY_NAME = "my_policy_name";

    private void mqttConnect(){
        try {
            mqttManager.connect(clientKeyStore, new AWSIotMqttClientStatusCallback() {
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    }

    private Notification getNotification() {
        final int requestCode = notifyID;
        Intent intent = new Intent(VoxIotService.this, CheckUpdate.class);

        final int flags = PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE;
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, intent, flags);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(NOTIFY_TITLE)
                .setContentText(NOTIFY_INIT_MESSAGE)
                .setStyle(new Notification.InboxStyle()
                .addLine(NOTIFY_INIT_MESSAGE)
                .setSummaryText(NOTIFY_SUMMARY_TEXT))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId("My-Channel-ID");
        }

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        return notification;
    }

    private void startForegroundService() {
        NotificationManager notificationManager;
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("My-Channel-ID", "My-Channel-Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        startForeground(1,getNotification());
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
            ...

        startForegroundService();
        clientManager = new AmazonClientManager(this);

        clientId = ClientId.id(this);

        credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(), // context
                COGNITO_POOL_ID, // Identity Pool ID
                MY_REGION // Region
        );

        Region region = Region.getRegion(MY_REGION);

        // MQTT Client
        mqttManager = new AWSIotMqttManager(clientId, CUSTOMER_SPECIFIC_ENDPOINT);

        AuthenticationResultType authenticationResultType = new AuthenticationResultType();
        String idToken = authenticationResultType.getIdToken();

        Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
        logins.put(CUSTOMER_SPECIFIC_ENDPOINT, idToken);
        credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);

        mqttManager.setKeepAlive(60);

        // Set Last Will and Testament for MQTT.  On an unclean disconnect (loss of connection)
        // AWS IoT will publish this message to alert other clients.
        if(true == APP_WILL_STATE) {
            AWSIotMqttLastWillAndTestament lwt = new AWSIotMqttLastWillAndTestament("my-topic",
                    "Android client lost connection", AWSIotMqttQos.QOS0);
            mqttManager.setMqttLastWillAndTestament(lwt);
        }

        // IoT Client (for creation of certificate if needed)
        mIotAndroidClient = new AWSIotClient(credentialsProvider);
        mIotAndroidClient.setRegion(region);

        keystorePath = getFilesDir().getPath();
        keystoreName = KEYSTORE_NAME;
        keystorePassword = KEYSTORE_PASSWORD;
        certificateId = CERTIFICATE_ID;

        // To load cert/key from keystore on filesystem
        try {
            if (AWSIotKeystoreHelper.isKeystorePresent(keystorePath, keystoreName)) {
                if (AWSIotKeystoreHelper.keystoreContainsAlias(certificateId, keystorePath,
                        keystoreName, keystorePassword)) {
                    // load keystore from file into memory to pass on connection
                    clientKeyStore = AWSIotKeystoreHelper.getIotKeystore(certificateId,
                            keystorePath, keystoreName, keystorePassword);

                    mqttConnect();
                } else {
                    //Log.i(TAG, "Key/cert " + certificateId + " not found in keystore.");
                }
            } else {
                //Log.i(TAG, "Keystore " + keystorePath + "/" + keystoreName + " not found.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred retrieving cert/key from keystore.", e);
        }

        if (clientKeyStore == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Cert/key was not found in keystore - creating new key and certificate.");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Create a new private key and certificate. This call
                    // creates both on the server and returns them to the
                    // device.
                    CreateKeysAndCertificateRequest createKeysAndCertificateRequest =
                                new CreateKeysAndCertificateRequest();
                    createKeysAndCertificateRequest.setSetAsActive(true);
                    final CreateKeysAndCertificateResult createKeysAndCertificateResult;
                    createKeysAndCertificateResult =
                                mIotAndroidClient.createKeysAndCertificate(createKeysAndCertificateRequest);
                    Log.i(TAG,
                                "Cert ID: " +
                                        createKeysAndCertificateResult.getCertificateId() +
                                        " created.");

                    // store in keystore for use in MQTT client
                    // saved as alias "default" so a new certificate isn't
                    // generated each run of this application
                        AWSIotKeystoreHelper.saveCertificateAndPrivateKey(certificateId,
                            createKeysAndCertificateResult.getCertificatePem(),
                            createKeysAndCertificateResult.getKeyPair().getPrivateKey(),
                            keystorePath, keystoreName, keystorePassword);

                    // load keystore from file into memory to pass on
                    // connection
                    clientKeyStore = AWSIotKeystoreHelper.getIotKeystore(certificateId,
                                keystorePath, keystoreName, keystorePassword);

                    // Attach a policy to the newly created certificate.
                    // This flow assumes the policy was already created in
                    // AWS IoT and we are now just attaching it to the
                    // certificate.
                    if (false) {
                        AttachPrincipalPolicyRequest policyAttachRequest =
                                    new AttachPrincipalPolicyRequest();
                        policyAttachRequest.setPolicyName(AWS_IOT_POLICY_NAME);
                        policyAttachRequest.setPrincipal(createKeysAndCertificateResult
                                    .getCertificateArn());
                        mIotAndroidClient.attachPrincipalPolicy(policyAttachRequest);
                    } else {
                        AttachPolicyRequest attachPolicyReq = new AttachPolicyRequest(); 
                        attachPolicyReq.setPolicyName(AWS_IOT_POLICY_NAME);
                        attachPolicyReq.setTarget(createKeysAndCertificateResult.getCertificateArn());
                        mIotAndroidClient.attachPolicy(attachPolicyReq);
                    }

                    mqttConnect();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,
                                "Exception occurred when generating new private key and certificate.",
                                e);
                }
            }
        }).start();
        }
    }
```

Here is the relevant portion of the logs :

```
    MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:738)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:363)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.convertException(ConscryptEngine.java:1134)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1089)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:876)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:747)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:712)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:858)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.access$100(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:731)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:241)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:724)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920) 
     Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:656)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:615)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:505)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:425)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:353)
        at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
        at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:90)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$2.checkServerTrusted(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:163)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:255)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptEngine.java:1638)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer(NativeSsl.java:569)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1095)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1079)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:876) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:747) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:712) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:858) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.access$100(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:731) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:241) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:220) 
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:159) 
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:724) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920) 
     Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:656) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:615) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:505) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:425) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:353) 
        at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94) 
        at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:90) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$2.checkServerTrusted(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:163) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:255) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptEngine.java:1638) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(Native Method) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer(NativeSsl.java:569) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1095) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1079) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:876) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:747) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:712) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:858) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.access$100(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:731) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:241) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:220) 
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:159) 
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:724) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

further information(2021/12/9): I use the same account to create an identity pool in Amazon Cognito, and set up different regions for testing. If the region is set to us-west-2, the MQTT connection fails, and the region is set to ap-southeast-1 then the MQTT connection succeeds. What will be the effect on identity pool? Or any other suggestions?

(notice: Android 8/9/10/11 phones are normal, only android 12 has an error message.)

Comment: Did your app do something when receiving notifications? The exception above is related to SSL. The server you're connected to is misconfigured. Not related to notification unless you are making any api call prior to receiving the notification. You can check your url endpoint here ->https://www.digicert.com/help/

Comment: We need more information here, Please read the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on what a good question needs then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70163257/edit) the question.